# Is there a way to tell what nib my UIView has awoken from?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uikit

I have a subclass of UIView that can be initialized from a variety of nibs. Is there any way to access from within my UIView class which nib it was initialized by?

As you can see below, currently I set the tag and then am able to check that value from within my class, but I was just curious if UIViews were in anyway aware of what nib they are attached to, or if there was some way to access it through the decoder. Mahalo if anyone knows.

```
NSArray *nibViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:viewNibName owner:self options:nil];
self.viewInstance = (ViewClass *)[nibViews objectAtIndex:0];
self.viewInstance.tag = VIEW_INSTANCE_ID;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe there's currently a good way for an object to find out what nib it's being loaded from. Remember: any object that implements NSCoding can be stored in a nib file, not just views. If there were a way to find out, it would probably be by calling a method in NSKeyedArchiver or NSCoder, and I don't see anything there.

If you really believe that you need this capability, I'd suggest defining a protocol with a method like "-(NSString*)nibName" and implementing it in your classes that load the nib. Then, you can connect your view to the "File's Owner" proxy icon in the nib, and it can query the nib owner for the name of the nib. UIViewController already has -nibName and -nibBundle methods, so this would require very little work in most cases.

That said, I would not recommend doing such a thing. If you've got a view class that behaves differently depending on the nib that loads it, I'd take that as a strong signal that your code should be re-factored. I'd either move the code that depends on the nib name to a controller class, or split the code into two or more separate view classes.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you subclass a UIViewController (with its main view) instead of a UIView directly...? 
UIViewControllers has 2 property: "nibName" and "nibBundle" that could do what you are asking...

Comment: I'm adding a number of these view objects to the screen at a time and figured it would be more lightweight to just use UIView if I could get away with it.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
private var nibNameAssociationKey: UInt8 = 0

extension UIView {

    var nibName: String {
        get {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &nibNameAssociationKey) as String
        }
        set(newValue) {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &nibNameAssociationKey, newValue, UInt(OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN))
        }
    }

    class func loadFromNibNamed(nibNamed: String, bundle : NSBundle? = nil) -> UIView? {
        var view = UINib(nibName: nibNamed, bundle: bundle).instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil)[0] as? UIView
        view?.nibName = nibNamed
        return view
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var someView = SomeView.loadFromNibNamed("SomeSubviewOfSomeView") as SomeView?
...
var myNibName = someView!.nibName // will be "SomeSubviewOfSomeView"
```